# Setting umask in Git / Gitolite

Tags: git, permissions, gitolite, umask

I have set up Git and Gitolite, and at some point I recall having seen an "umask" setting, in one of the configuration files. Does this set the permissions for all files I sync using Git? That is exactly what I need. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [umask settings in Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/v2.3.1/doc/tips-notes.mkd#umask-umask-setting) are there for changing the umask for newly created repos (and not about the files managed in versions by those repos).
See [gitolite.rc doc](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/rc.html):

> `$REPO_UMASK`, octal, default 0077
>
> The default `UMASK` that gitolite uses makes all the repos and their contents have `rwx------` permissions. People who want to run gitweb realise that this will not do.
>
> The correct way to deal with this is to give this variable a value like `0027` (note the syntax: the leading 0 is required), and then make the user running the webserver (apache, `www-data`, whatever) a member of the 'git' group.
>
> If you've already installed gitolite then existing files will have to be fixed up manually (for a umask or `0027`, that would be `chmod -R g+rX`). This is because `umask` only affects permissions on newly created files, not existing ones.

This settings is similar to the one use when you create directly a git repo (without gitolite):

```
core.sharedRepository
```

> When `group` (or `true`), the repository is made shareable between several users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are group-writable).
> When `all` (or `world` or `everybody`), the repository will be readable by all users, additionally to being `group-shareable`.
> When `umask` (or `false`), git will use permissions reported by `umask`.

See also "[How do I share a Git repository with multiple users on a machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine)" for more.

When you have conflicts between platforms relative to permissions, you also have the option to "[instruct git to ignore file permissions changes](https://superuser.com/questions/261060/git-how-can-i-config-git-to-ignore-file-permissions-changes)" (`git config core.fileMode false`).

Update: This answer covers gitolite 2. With gitolite 3 the setting changed from `$REPO_UMASK` to just `$UMASK`.