# Git/Gitolite permissions with redmine

Tags: git, redmine, gitolite

In a docker setup, i've got the following :

- git container, with gitolite managed repositories
- redmine container, with an access to the repositories through a volume mount

The two containers shares the same uid/gid for git user.

Redmine user is listed in git group, so redmine user is able to browse in repositories, but partially as follows :

It seems that some files inside each repo is not accessible by the git group for the redmine user ; I can experience it if I'm trying to access my repos through redmine webapp.

If I'm chown-ing all my repos as redmine:redmine, everything is fine, but that's not satisfying.

Can I do something else than sharing the same user across my containers ?
(run redmine as a git user)

Edit :

Just read [Setting umask in Git / Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086325/setting-umask-in-git-gitolite)

Seems to work if I'm settings permissions like this way chmod -R g+rX

Comment: probably you should establish a shared repository (`git init --shared...`), then `chown` it  to a dedicated group (`chown -R :<the_group> /path/to/repo`), and then include all users, including `redmine` into that group. Then I guess all those dances with umask won't be required, cause `git` takes care of proper access modes in this case (not sure about `gitolite` but I guess, it also respects that setting)